# Why I can not pass parameter when http.delete in AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I have function to call http.delete and pass a parameter flag:

```
function softDeleteDatasource(datasourceId,flag) {
            var url = baseUrl + datasourceId;
            return $http.delete(url, {'currentFieldSetFlag':flag});
        }
```

Then I assume I can get the req.body with following code. However, I always get `undefined` in the `console.log`. I used exactly same code in `http.post` and it works fine when passing parameter.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();
router.delete('/:datasourceId', jsonParser, function(req, res) {
   console.log(req.body.currentFieldSetFlag);
}
```

I am confused why the same code can not pass parameter in `http.delete`? anyone know how to pass it?

Comment: First step in debugging this would be to go to your network tab in the browser console and inspect the request. Did angular send json, or was the parameter added to the url.

Comment: @KevinB it looks it does not send the json but I do not understand why, since the same code of http.post works well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HTTP spec allows for bodies on DELETEs, but some clients do not send them and some proxies/servers will strip/ignore them if present.  This ought to work to pass it as a querystring parameter:

```
return $http.delete(url, {params: {'currentFieldSetFlag':flag}});
```